# QTableView has extra column divider before first column header

Tags: c++, qt

I'm doing Qt on Mac desktop. I have a QTableView. It appears to have an extra column divider in the header before the first column. See the screen shot.

[image]

You can see what I mean right before "Name". It's as if there's a 0-width column before column 0. I am guessing that this is to allow for row headers, which I don't have. That is only a guess.

Is it possible to get rid of this? I don't know if I'm doing something to cause this or not doing something to suppress it, or if there's nothing I can do.

I've included my headerData() method.

```
/**
 * Return header.
 */
QVariant
SetupDevicesModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const {
    QVariant retVal;
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0: retVal = QString("Name"); break;
            case 1: retVal = QString("Phone Number"); break;
            case 2: retVal = QString("IP Host"); break;
            case 3: retVal = QString("IP Port"); break;
            case 4: retVal = QString("Video Stream"); break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is divider between horizontal and vertical headers. Did you hide your vertical header or it is visible but blank? Try `ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);` to hide verical header.

Comment: I wasn't touching vertical headers. Per this suggestion and the one from Maxim Paperno, I was able to get this fixed. It was a small thing, but it bugged me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is a result of having a vertical header.  The vertical header can be hidden entirely with `QTableView::verticalHeader()->hide();`

The top-left corner of a `QTableView` is actually a button which can be used to select all cells in a table. The button can be disabled with `QTableView::setCornerButtonEnabled(false)` but that doesn't hide it or change appearance.

The application's style also has an effect. For example with "Fusion" style, you may not see that extra line. It should be possible to hide that line using custom styling or painting, but if you don't need the vertical header anyway then the easiest way to remove that line is to hide the header.

Comment: Thank you. Calling hide() from the window constructor took care of it.

Comment: Two years later, I hit this again and couldn't remember the solution. You can fix it in Qt Designer as well. In the properties for the view, under header is a boolean for verticalHeaderVisible. Click it off.